# how to take input in list in python with spaces like ["Isha", "Chandoygya", "Sri Vasya", "Mandukya", "Sri"]

Tags: python-3.x

I want to take input from user in list. Input may be strings like

```
["Isha", "Chandoygya", "Sri Vasya", "Mandukya", "Sri"]
```

If I use this:

```
my_list=(str(x) for x in input().split())
```

then each new input is seperated by one space.
But I want to take input like "Sri Vasya".
How can I do it ?

Comment: There is no way for Python to know when you want to keep it intact as a two word string and when you want to split it into two.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [7]: mylist = input("Enter comma (',') separated names: ").split(',')
Enter comma (',') separated names: Isha, Chandoygya, Sri Vasya, Mandukya, Sri

In [8]: mylist
Out[8]: ['Isha', ' Chandoygya', ' Sri Vasya', ' Mandukya', ' Sri']

In [9]: mylist = [name.strip() for name in mylist]

In [10]: mylist
Out[10]: ['Isha', 'Chandoygya', 'Sri Vasya', 'Mandukya', 'Sri']
```